# Can any one help me to use threading in etree.iterparse in python?

Tags: python, xml, multithreading

I am parsing the huge XML file with a size of more than 20 GB. I am trying to implement threading for parallel processing.

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.